# Map array and find values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array and an object. In the array I have a list of Products and in the object I have a category.

What I should to do is to find a code in the array equals to the category.Code .

So I have thought to do a .map of the array, but I don't know how to return back only the values equal to category.code.

```
console.log("this.props.products: ", this.props.products)
console.log("this.props.category: ", this.props.category)

let findProducts = this.props.products.Products.map((product) => {
    console.log("product_", product.Categories.MainCode)
    product.Categories.MainCode == this.props.category.Code
})

console.log("findProducts: ", findProducts)
```

The `findProducts` returns me a list of undefined.

Basically I want obtain only the this.props.products.Products.Categories.MainCode == this.props.category.Code

(that should be more than one).

How can I do?? Thank you

Comment: Give us an example array of products so we can test out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` is not the right function to use in this case. Instead, use [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function which will return an array of only those products for which the callback function returns true

```
let findProducts = this.props.products.Products.filter((product) => {
  return product.Categories.MainCode == this.props.category.Code;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need in this case is `array.filter` method, which expects a function to decide if an element should be in the result array.

```js
let findProducts = this.props.products.Products.filter((product) => {
    return product.Categories.MainCode === this.props.category.Code
})
``
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with filter

```
var arrayFiltered = this.props.products.Products.filter(item => item.Categories.MainCode == this.props.category.code);
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to *return* something from that mapping lambda...

```
let findProducts = this.props.products.Products.map(product => {
  console.log('product_', product.Categories.MainCode);
  return product.categories.MainCode == this.props.category.Code;
});
```

Besides, it looks like a use case for `.filter` rather than `.map`.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a standard use of [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
let findProducts = this.props.products.Products.filter((product) => {
   return product.Categories.MainCode == this.props.category.Code
})
```

Filter returns only the entries for which true is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let findProducts = this.props.products.Products.map((product) => {
    if (product.Categories.MainCode === this.props.category.Code) return product
})
```

Comment: `map` function returns a value in each iteration. In your code, when if condition will be false, undefined will be returned.